# UWP - Write file using C codes

Tags: c++, c, file, uwp, c++-cx

I have a `C++` UWP app that calls a `C` function which writes to a file .e.g.

```
FILE * fp = fopen ("file.txt", "w+");
fprintf(fp, "Hello");
fclose(fp);
```

`fopen()` failes with error `13` which means that there are insufficient permission on the directory. How can I ensure that the `C` function can write to a file?

Comment: Do you have permission to update that file? Right-click and open it in notepad, make a change and try to save it to check. Is the file already open by some other application, like your UWP app?

Comment: This is related to your application permission, not the function, please read further at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Comment: @JonnathanQ Thanks I managed to find a solution using the link provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `UWP` runs in a sandbox, I solved it by getting a writable file path in `C++`:

```
StorageFolder^ localFolder = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
String^ path = localFolder->Path;
```

Then I passed the path to the `C` program.